# Как вставить в свойство объекта значение функции?

Tags: javascript

Как вставить в объект js значение функции. Я пробую вот такую конструкцию (код с jQuery).

```
foo = $('.bar');
obj = {
    0: function(){
        if (foo[0].id){
          return foo[0].id //Если у элемента есть id, то его надо вернуть
        }
       }
}
```

На выходе у меня получается

```
Object {0: function()}
```

А нужно чтобы в свойстве был id элемента. Как это можно сделать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Еще забыл сказать, что такая конструкция у меня используется  в цикле, поэтому и приходится проверять id, потому что его может не быть и нужно будет оставить поле пустым.

Comment: в js нет определения "оставить поле пустым". Что под этим понимаете Вы?

Comment: это не суть , что надо сделать с полем. Главное в него передать foo.id

Comment: что означает выражение "это не суть"? Это по-русски? Знаю слово "сыть": "Ах ты, волчья сыть, травяной мешок ..."

Comment: @Igor Суть - Самое главное и существенное в чём-н.

Comment: Очень даже по-русски.

Comment: @AlexPenskoni у вас, кстати, почему-то в `if`-е идёт `foo[0].id`, а в `return`-е - `foo.id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {
    0: (function(){ ... })()
};
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Нубский вопрос получился, конечно. Но что делать, все учимся.